# Does E.T. have very high IQ?

Tags: et-the-extra-terrestrial

Is this pure speculation or would the IQ of ET be around 300? I read some scifi works have stated that the IQ of certain characters were this and that, was there anything like that for E.T?

Comment: I think the book states that the IQ of his species was a lot higher than that of humans, yes. He was also a lot older I think.

Comment: @MrLister which book?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/E-T-The-Extra-Terrestrial-Novel-William-Kotzwinkle/dp/0743216024

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, an IQ of 300 is undefined, because the scale does not go that high. The IQ as per definition is calculated so that over a specific population, age group, etc it has a mean of 100 and a deviation of 15. This means you can not use this measurement to measure the intelligence of a non-human (or even of a human not within the age group of your test)

Popular "internet truths" such as a cockroach or a pocket calculator or a horse (or a non-human fictional character) having an IQ of X are all incorrect and have no scientific basis.

To measure the intelligence of E.T. you have to create a different metric, the IQ score system can probably not be used. Even if you used it, it is impossible to get a score of 300 with any notable test currently used. You have to create a specific test just for this purpose, which you would need to call something else, not IQ.

Comment: Do you have any link to something that confirms "it is impossible to get a score of 300"  I do not think that statement is correct... I Think it is incredibly unlikely but not mathematically impossible.

Comment: @Chad what vsz means is that none of the [modern IQ tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iq#Modern_tests) are capable of measuring a score of 300. Since IQ itself is defined in terms of the tests that are used to measure it, that's what vsz means by "the scale does not go that high"

Comment: @Tacroy - I am pretty sure the woodcock johnson assessment is capable of it and is included in the list you linked.

Comment: @Chad - my point is, that even if you created or have chosen a test which goes to 300, it would not be adequate to measure the IQ of a non-human. The IQ test is designed to test how the reasoning and problem-solving capability of humans of a specific group deviate from the average of that group. You might well say that the intelligence of ET is higher than that of the average human, but you can not say it about IQ as a measurable quantity.

Comment: @vsz - That is not how it reads though...  *Even if you used it, it is impossible to get a score of 300 with any notable test currently used.* ... and that is my point it sounds like you are saying no test is capable of producing a score of 300+ and that is not true.

Comment: @Chad - I mean that tests usually don't go above 300 (they usually don't go above 150, and achieving a completely correct result is usually handled as an error), and *even if they do*, it wouldn't mean much if not performed by a member of the target population.

Comment: @Vsz - Well that is not what you said you used the word impossible.  The more comprehensive tests are capable of assessing much higher scores.

Comment: @Chad The Woodcock Johnson assessment is not an IQ test at least it does not deliver its results in IQ. Their website says: *"Scores: PR, SS, AE, GE, NCE, stanine, T score, z score, W score, RPI, CALP levels, and developmental zones"*. Having a score of 300 on some test does not mean anything if you don't have a metric for it. I could write a test where the score goes from 0 to 200000, with the average people getting a score of 10000. In that test a score of 300 would be pretty low. Do you have any info about what IQ a 300 score on the WJa corresponds to (if there is a relation at all)?

Comment: But the results can be used to calculate an IQ score well over 300... though it is not realistic to expect any human to ever actually achieve that.  There is no IQ test there are assessments of knowledge and abilities that are used calculate IQ's.  Whether or not the score is meaningful is irrelavent the to **possiblity** of achieving the score.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the IQ test and which ETs. They're beings same as us, but more advanced and evolved. Usually IQ tests are designed for humans, sometimes only for specific age group or society. If they're connected with 4th/5th dimensional realms, I'm sure they can get the highest possible score.